# PyCharm: always mark venv directory as excluded

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

In Python 3, I've moved away from creating virtualenvs in `~/.virtualenvs` and towards keeping them in the project directory `./venv`

However now search results in every PyCharm project include results from `venv` subdirectories, until you manually right-click and exclude them from the project.

How to omit directories named `venv` from PyCharm indexing/searching, globally?

Comment: It is poor practice to do this: the virtual environment and the project source should be kept separate (the same venv can be used on multiple projects after all).

Comment: It's not just the venv I want to address this issue for.  There are also for example files such as `coverage.xml` that I always want excluded from search results.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to call it poor practice, since many users simply prefer having one venv per project.

Comment: I certainly would not call this "poor practice", it's actually what I encourage my developers to do. We consider venvs entirely disposable and recreate them quickly and often and are pretty happy with the way it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior in recent versions of PyCharm now excludes `venv` (and `.venv`) on new projects. I can not find a related issue on their [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) nor a mention in the changelog, so I don't know in which version this was fixed, but it's no longer an issue in 2021.3.3 at least.

If you're still seeing the old behaviour, consider to update your PyCharm version.

Answer (score 18):

In `File > Settings > Project: > Project Structure` at the bottom is `Exclude files:` You can put something in there like

`venv` or `venv;coverage.xml` (given your comment)

It doesn't seem to recognize paths (e.g. `foo/venv`), but this does what you requested.

Comment: That menu applies to the current project.  The question is about creating global exclude settings.

Comment: What seems to work is to manually mark such folders as excluded in Project Structure > (select a project) > right-click on the desired directories in the central pane so that those names are added in the right-hand pane (PyCharm 2017.3)

Answer (score 15):

You can globally exclude a directory in PyCharm by following the Breadcrumb trail:

`Settings > Editor > File Types > Ignore Files and Folders:`

At the bottom is a text box where you can input the symbolic link `./venv` relative to your projects base directory, highlighted in the picture:

[image]

After that, new projects have `./venv` excluded by default. You don't need to repeat the above steps for new projects. In use, "Find in Path" shows:

[image]

P.S. I also started keeping my venvs inside their project directories. Once you have dozens of projects it just becomes convenient.

Comment: This looks promising, but it has the unacceptable side-effect that every 3rd-party project installed to the venv gets a red squiggle underneath and cannot be browsed into with ctrl+click.  PyCharm now thinks *Cannot find declaration to go to*, even though they are actually installed in the project's venv. Any idea about that?

Comment: @wim Good point! Couldn't reproduce, my 3rd party libraries(projects?) are pip installed. "Go to declaration" or ctrl+click work opening the definition, no red scribble, (and the internals don't pollute search.) Side-effect *fix*: `venv` path/file structure is stable, exclude the list of core files in the text box; Anything besides core `venv` files isn't global anyway, and can be excluded/hidden case-by-case using the method in the other answer.