# PyCharm: How to disable certain CSS file code complete?

Tags: css, django, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Django REST framework uses Bootstrap and has its own CSS files in it. It seems like PyCharm imports those files for code completion popups. The things is, I don't want those as I use different CSS framework and in fact, it's confusing me because all those Bootstrap autocomplete popups when I'm trying to set CSS classes and so on.

So my question is, is there any way I can disable code completion popups from certain CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

I did not face with this problem until now,but I think you should disable these folders is Pycharm, try this :

> Settings|Directories -> Use Exclude button on folder

Comment: It wouldn't even let me do so as it's in venv directory.

Comment: see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985912/pycharm-always-mark-venv-directory-as-excluded?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)