# Can pycharm testing configurations be exported for use/re-import into another project?

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to export the testing configurations that can be reimported to a fresh project?

Background:   Even though the `venv` folder is *Excluded* it is opened up. When I click on the folder to collapse it, the `pycharm` hangs (*macOS* beach ball). This has happened repeatedly.

While I might consider recreating the project, the problem is there are many testing configurations that are too valuable to simply throw away.  I need a way to save them and pull them into the newly re-done project.

[image]

Comment: I think the only solution that's integrated with the IDE is setting [**Store as project file**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#share-configurations) in the run configurations. Some paths are likely to be hardcoded (like Project, Interpreter, CWD and path)... Using search/replaced on the resulting XML files (by hand or writing a script) is likely the most efficient way to get it done, because project/interpreter is usually managed by the IDE some of those paths (like Project) will be an IDE string not a filepath.

Comment: I've also [stopped keeping the venvs inside the project folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45985912) it's just not worth the hassle. I might change Python versions or packages often and just keep all the venvs in a master folder organized by name. If I need to fall back on a older venv I change it in settings and likely have to also change them individually in the run configurations, that seems to be the optimal workflow at the moment.

Comment: @bad_coder: nice to see you drop in. i'll look into that "store as project file".  feel free to make that answer  . separately, I agree with venv's outside the project but this project also needs to build on the cloud [not to mention _I_ don't make these choices] so it goes there.

Comment: I'm in short supply of free time this month if I get a chance I'll write an answer but I can't make any promises atm. If some reader want to beat me to it feel free to.

Comment: @bad_coder  I created a proxy answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bad_coder has provided a workable answer in his comment.

> I think the only solution that's integrated with the IDE is setting [Store as project file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#share-configurations) in the run configurations. Some paths are likely to be hardcoded (like Project, Interpreter, CWD and path)... Using search/replaced on the resulting XML files (by hand or writing a script) is likely the most efficient way to get it done, because project/interpreter is usually managed by the IDE some of those paths (like Project) will be an IDE string not a filepath.

More details on this approach to follow..